# Does it make any sense that I use multi processes to insert data to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, io, multiprocessing

I need to insert about 300 millions data records into MySQL, I wonder does it make any sense that I use multi-processes to make it ?

**Situation 1** : 300 millions records insert into only one table.

**Situation 2** : 300 millions records insert into multi tables.

What are the bottlenecks is on these two situations ?

The data source is about 800+ txt files.

---

**I know there's a command `LOAD DATA INFILE`, I just want to understand this question. :D**

Comment: What is the source of these records (file, other database, ...)?

Comment: @peterm Plain txt files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have lots of data consider using `LOAD DATA`. It's **the fastest** method of importing data from files according to mysql docs.

> **[LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)**
>   The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table **at a very high speed**.
>
> **[Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html)**
>   When loading a table from a text file, use LOAD DATA INFILE. **This is
>   usually 20 times faster** than using INSERT statements. See Section
>   13.2.6, “LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax”.
>   ...
>   **INSERT is still much slower for loading data than LOAD DATA INFILE**, even when using the strategies just outlined.

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES; -- use IGNORE if you have a header line in your file
```

Comment: Thanks, @peterm, I know LOAD DATA INFILE, I just curious about this question, could you help to explain ?

Comment: @MrROY In order to be able to try to answer that particular question  intelligently you have to provide much more information: what engine is being used, where client processes reside, what is the exact code that you're using to insert etc.